# Laravel 6.4 index.php URL rewriting .htaccess error

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-6

This is not a question on how to remove `index.php` with `.htaccess` file kind of issue.

I have setup a Laravel 6.4 application in my local Apache server. I have moved my public directory to `/var/www/html` and edited the default vhost file to load it when `http://localhost` is typed in.

**The reason I changed the default vhost to point to `/var/www/html/public` directory is that I need to load the Laravel application when the ip address is called from another computer in the Local Area Network.**

When I typed in `http://localhost`, it works fine and the Default Laravel welcome page with `Login` and `Register` links on the top right is displayed.

But when I navigate to `http://localhost/login` or  `http://localhost/register` it gives 404 error. **And then when I type in `http://localhost/index.php/login` or  `http://localhost/index.php/register`**, the pages load fine without any issue.

*I tried making changes to the .htaccess file using the references found on the internet but had no luck so far.*

**Follwing is my current setup.**

The Laravel application files are put in a level before the `public` directory in a directory called `testapp` and I have modified the `index.php` file to point to that.

Please see the console outputs below for details.

My OS version is Ubuntu 19.04.

Following is the directory structure inside `/var/www/html`.

```
isuru@isuru-aspire-e5-574g /var/www/html $ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root     4096 Nov  3 02:34 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root     4096 Nov  2 16:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root      168 Jun  5 06:29 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 13 isuru www-data 4096 Aug  9 13:26 phpmyadmin
drwxr-xr-x  5 isuru www-data 4096 Nov  3 12:41 public
drwxr-xr-x 13 isuru www-data 4096 Nov  3 02:34 testapp
```

Following are the directory structures in testapp and public folders.

**`testapp` folder**

```
isuru@isuru-aspire-e5-574g /var/www/html/testapp $ ls -al
total 712
drwxr-xr-x  13 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  root       4096 Nov  3 02:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x   6 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 app
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data   1686 Nov  3 02:34 artisan
drwxr-xr-x   3 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data   1531 Nov  3 02:34 composer.json
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data 178175 Nov  3 02:34 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x   2 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 config
drwxr-xr-x   5 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 database
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data    220 Nov  3 02:34 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data    777 Nov  3 13:01 .env
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data    726 Nov  3 02:34 .env.example
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data    111 Nov  3 02:34 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data    163 Nov  3 02:34 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 703 isuru www-data  20480 Nov  3 02:34 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data   1144 Nov  3 02:34 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data 429975 Nov  3 02:34 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data   1297 Nov  3 02:34 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x   4 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 public
drwxr-xr-x   6 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 resources
drwxr-xr-x   2 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 routes
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data    563 Nov  3 02:34 server.php
drwxrwxr-x   5 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 storage
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data    174 Nov  3 02:34 .styleci.yml
drwxr-xr-x   4 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:34 tests
drwxr-xr-x  41 isuru www-data   4096 Nov  3 02:35 vendor
-rw-r--r--   1 isuru www-data    538 Nov  3 02:34 webpack.mix.js
```

**`public` folder**

```
isuru@isuru-aspire-e5-574g /var/www/html/public $ ls -al
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 5 isuru www-data 4096 Nov  3 12:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root     4096 Nov  3 02:34 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 isuru www-data    0 Nov  3 01:39 access.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 isuru www-data 4096 Nov  3 02:35 css
-rw-r--r-- 1 isuru www-data    0 Nov  3 01:39 error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 isuru www-data    0 Nov  3 02:35 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 isuru www-data  593 Nov  3 12:41 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 isuru www-data 1839 Nov  3 11:59 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 isuru www-data 4096 Nov  3 02:35 js
-rw-r--r-- 1 isuru www-data   71 Nov  3 02:35 mix-manifest.json
drwxr-xr-x 4 isuru www-data 4096 Nov  3 02:35 public
-rw-r--r-- 1 isuru www-data   24 Nov  3 02:35 robots.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 isuru www-data   40 Nov  3 12:39 storage -> /var/www/html/testapp/storage/app/public
```

Following are the contents of my `.htaccess` file and `index.php` files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>


<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../testapp/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../testapp/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Please note that creating a vhost directly to public folder is working perfectly fine and when I set this up in my production server (Shared), it too works fine. I have replicated exactly what I'm doing when I setup a Laravel application in the production server (Shared) except changing the default vhost file to public.

**Please provide me any instructions to solve this issue. If I can force index.php to every URL, it works for me too. Thanks in advance for any help from anybody.**

Comment: is `mod_rewrite` enabled (Check `a2query -m rewrite`)

Comment: Why you need to move your public folder to `/var/www/html`? I believe you just need to point your default vhost to `/var/www/html/testapp/public`..

Comment: @apokryfos Yes it is enabled.

Comment: @nmfzone Yes I could do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the findings on the internet, I have solved my problem.

The issue was to set /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to AllowOverride all to /var/www/html and /usr/share directories.

now my apache2.conf looks like this.

```
.... content above

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>


.... content below
```

Thanks everyone who commented. This was an easy fix all along.